# What is the correct format for SECURITY_PRINCIPAL in LDAP authentication using "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"

Tags: java, ldap, jndi, spring-ldap, spring-security-ldap

```
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxx");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "CN=username");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, pwd);
env.put(Context.REFERRAL,"follow");
```

I need to search only the "CN" in the particular domain. Tried with above way and many formats, but end up with the error "LDAP error code 49 AcceptSecurityContext error data 52e v2580".

Comment: It is the DN of the user. Typically you have to bind as an admin user to do the search for the user, then attempt to rebind as that user when found.

Comment: @user207421, Can you give me an example?

Comment: An example, of what? Binding as your admin user, which I don't know? Searching for the user on some attribute that I don't know? Trying to log in as the user, which you already have above except for not using the DN?

Comment: There is no admin user in this AD as it is not containing LDAP groups.

Comment: A few weeks back I got a solution like SECURITY_PRINCIPAL="domain\username", but not sure whether the syntax is the same.

Comment: It's the bind dn, it should be either in this format `domain.com\username` either in this one `cn=username,dc=domain,dc=com`

Comment: I have used them both by, passing SECURITY_PRINCIPAL value from application.properties file, but I am getting "LDAP error code 49 AcceptSecurityContext error data 52e v2580" for both types even credentials are correct.

Answer (score 1):

The LDAP error code 49 AcceptSecurityContext error data 52e Returns when username is valid but password/credential is invalid.

We have several examples for [JNDI Against Microsoft Active Directory](https://bitbucket.org/jwilleke/examples/src/master/Examples-JNDI/src/com/willeke/samples/ldap/jndi/ADConnection.java).